# Start gvim multiple tabs, cursor at specified line in each one

Tags: vim

I can start Gvim and be positioned at a line

gvim file1 +10

or I can start Gvim and have 2 files in tabs

gvim -p file1 file2

is there an invocation which does

gvim file1 +10 file2 +20

the above opens with file1 at line 20, file2 at line 1

I want file1 at 10, file2 at 20.

Thanks,
Kent

Comment: Please post this question to http://superuser.com/

Comment: Please, enough with the vim community dispersing stuff. Some answers are simple. Other answers require vim-scripting which definitively goes to SO, and not SU.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte - wasting your words. Some of here'people loooove to move stuff around.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this ?

```
gvim -p file1 file2 -c 10 -c tabn -c 20 -c 1tabn
```

Comment: Yes, that is very nice, and a generally useful technique, passing a list of commands to execute.

Thanks,
Kent